# Silverlight controls resize themselves at runtime

Tags: silverlight, resize, controls, translate, coordinate

I have an app with two versions. One is a standard silverlight app running withing the default web page (Running on windows 7). The other is a Windows Store app (running on windows 8) with almost the exact same XAML and code behind.

At runtime for both versions and operating systems, all controls on the main page resize. When this happens, then any coordinates that I get in mouse/pointer move events are not correct.

There are two acceptable solutions to this problem. The first is the set the main page so that the controls do not resize The second is the find a way to translate the resized coordinates to the un-resized coordinates.

I have tried quite a few things for quite a few hours and am hoping that someone has an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

In a Silverlight or winRT app, if you want to have some controls on a exact pixel position, you should use the Canvas controls as parent.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-Canvas-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx